# Same Code Returning Different Values in gcc compiler & Turbo C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

While Executing the below code for an array size of 2 with 2 identical elements say 11,11 both the compilers return the correct upper & lower bound of the array. But when executing the same for (1,1), gcc returns -1(number not in array) for upper bound whereas turbo C returns 1 for the same.

```
int binarylower(int a[],int m,int l,int u,int uorl)
{
    int mid;

    if(l<=u)
    {   //finds the mid position
        mid=(l+u)/2;
        if (uorl == 1)
        {
            if(m==a[mid])
            {
                if ((m != a[mid-1])|| (mid == 0 && m==a[mid]))
                {
                    return mid;
                }
                else
                {
                    return binarylower(a,m,l,mid-1,1);
                }
            }
            else if(m<a[mid])
            {
                return binarylower(a,m,l,mid-1,1);
            }
            else 
            {
                return binarylower(a,m,mid+1,u,1);
            }
        }
        else if(uorl == 2)
        {
            if(m==a[mid])
            {            
                if ((m != a[mid+1]))
                {
                    return mid;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    return binarylower(a,m,mid+1,u,2);
                    }
            }           
            else if(m < a[mid])
            {           
                return binarylower(a,m,l,mid-1,2);
            }           
            else
            {
                return binarylower(a,m,mid+1,u,2);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code supposed to be a binary search that finds either the lowest or the highest value in a range of contiguous values, depending on `uorl`? Have you heard of enumerations?

Comment: /Is the code supposed to be a binary search that finds either the lowest or the highest value in a range of contiguous values, depending on uorl?// Yes

Comment: // Have you heard of enumerations? //
Just a Bit

Answer (score 0):

#### There is a problem lurking in the code

One of your conditions is:

```
if ((m != a[mid-1]) || (mid == 0 && m == a[mid]))
```

This does not ensure that `mid-1` is in range.  The corresponding condition on the other branch does not check that `mid+1` is in range.  So, your code goes poking around parts of the array that it is not entitled to look at, leading to undefined behaviour.

---

#### Testing can only show the presence of bugs - not their absence!

Dijkstra said that, very sagely.

I added:

1. An `else return -1;` after the `else if (uorl == 2)` to prevent the compiler warning about a function not returning a value.
2. A test harness:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
       int array[] = { 11, 11 };
       printf("%d\n", binarylower(array, 11, 0, 1, 1));
       printf("%d\n", binarylower(array, 11, 0, 1, 2));
       return 0;
   }
   ```

With GCC on Mac OS X, that produced 0 and 1 as the answers, which seems reasonable and correct.  What did your test harness look like?

A more extensive test harness is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = { 11, 11 };
    printf("Array[0] = %d, [1] = %d\n", array[0], array[1]);
    printf("%d Lo: %d\n", 10, binarylower(array, 10, 0, 1, 1));
    printf("%d Hi: %d\n", 10, binarylower(array, 10, 0, 1, 2));
    printf("%d Lo: %d\n", 11, binarylower(array, 11, 0, 1, 1));
    printf("%d Hi: %d\n", 11, binarylower(array, 11, 0, 1, 2));
    printf("%d Lo: %d\n", 12, binarylower(array, 12, 0, 1, 1));
    printf("%d Hi: %d\n", 12, binarylower(array, 12, 0, 1, 2));

    array[1] = 13;
    printf("Array[0] = %d, [1] = %d\n", array[0], array[1]);
    printf("%d Lo: %d\n", 10, binarylower(array, 10, 0, 1, 1));
    printf("%d Hi: %d\n", 10, binarylower(array, 10, 0, 1, 2));
    printf("%d Lo: %d\n", 11, binarylower(array, 11, 0, 1, 1));
    printf("%d Hi: %d\n", 11, binarylower(array, 11, 0, 1, 2));
    printf("%d Lo: %d\n", 12, binarylower(array, 12, 0, 1, 1));
    printf("%d Hi: %d\n", 12, binarylower(array, 12, 0, 1, 2));
    printf("%d Lo: %d\n", 13, binarylower(array, 13, 0, 1, 1));
    printf("%d Hi: %d\n", 13, binarylower(array, 13, 0, 1, 2));
    printf("%d Lo: %d\n", 14, binarylower(array, 14, 0, 1, 1));
    printf("%d Hi: %d\n", 14, binarylower(array, 14, 0, 1, 2));

    return 0;
}
```

The output from that is:

```
Array[0] = 11, [1] = 11
10 Lo: -1
10 Hi: -1
11 Lo: 0
11 Hi: 1
12 Lo: -1
12 Hi: -1
Array[0] = 11, [1] = 13
10 Lo: -1
10 Hi: -1
11 Lo: 0
11 Hi: 0
12 Lo: -1
12 Hi: -1
13 Lo: 1
13 Hi: 1
14 Lo: -1
14 Hi: -1
```

That looks impeccable.

Comment: the code is working good for any data's other than 1,1(which returns -1 for upper bound)

Comment: That's the beauty of undefined behaviour...it can seem to work.  Since you've not shown your test code yet, I can't comment on your 1,1 finding.  To demonstrate the issue, we'd have to do things like:
`int array[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }; int *xx = &array[2]; int yy = binarylower(xx, 1, 0, 1, 1);`  When I run that test with `uorl` of 2, I get -1 returned from your code.  Your code is not quite taking sufficient care to keep the `mid` subscript within bounds of the array.  I've not yet coded a decent fix to your code - but I am satisfied that the source of the problem is diagnosed correctly.